# phpExcel multiple workbooks memory peformance

Tags: php, memory-management, report, phpexcel

I have a report thats generated using PHPexcel.  Its quite a large report 8 workbooks/tabs in total.  As you can imagine it uses up quite alot of memory and im starting to run into problems with it.

I was wondering what options would be best suited for me to reduce the memory load that it takes to generate this report.

The idea I had was to create the spreadsheet with 8 empty worksheets.  Save the file then load the file with the

```
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
```

Im not sure if im heading of in the right direction with this though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option to start with would be to look at the cell caching options that are explicitly written to reduce memory usage. These are described in section 4.2.1 of the developer documentation

Comment: I understand what you are staying but if I only want to load one work sheet at a time and edit it then it would make sense for me to just load that particular worksheet?

Comment: But then when you save, you're only saving a workbook with that one sheet - all well and good if that's all you want; but if you want to save with all 8 sheets then you need to load all 8 sheets. PHPExcel doesn't edit "in situ", replacing only the bits you've changed; it overwrites (if you save as the same filename) saving only what was actually loaded

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Is there no way to append a sheet onto the end without loading the entire thing?

Comment: No there isn't, I'm afraid the structure of EXcel files isn't conducive to working that way, and PHPExcel simply doesn't work that way